# how to handle subquery returning more than one value error?

Tags: sql, oracle

is there any other way to write this query so that it wont get the error?

```
select sum(Travelled_value) 
from travel_table 
where customer_id=(select distinct f.CUSTOMER_ID as agg 
                   from SEGMENT_table f 
                   JOIN bookin_table t 
                   ON f.CUSTOMER_ID=t.CUSTOMER_ID 
                   where t.booking_date BETWEEN sysdate 
                   AND sysdate+21 and f.type='NEW';)
```

here the three tables having customer_id as common.

Comment: Edit your question and show the error.

Comment: Perhaps you want `IN` sub-query, instead of `=` sub-query.

Comment: Replace `where customer_id=` with `where customer_id in `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will work, but it fixes many problems:

```
select sum(tt.Travelled_value)
from travel_table tt
where tt.customer_id in (select f.CUSTOMER_ID 
                         from SEGMENT_table f JOIN 
                              booking_table t
                              ON f.CUSTOMER_ID = t.CUSTOMER_ID
                         where t.booking_date between sysdate and sysdate+21 and
                               f.type = 'NEW'
                        );
```

Notes:

- You have a semicolon in the middle of the query.  It goes at the end.
- `select distinct` is not needed in an `in` subquery.
- You are using `sysdate` and comparing it to a date.  Are you sure you don't want `trunc(sysdate)`?  `sysdate` has a time component.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Travelled_value)
FROM travel_table
WHERE customer_id in
  (SELECT  f.CUSTOMER_ID 
  FROM SEGMENT_table f
  JOIN bookin_table t
  ON f.CUSTOMER_ID=t.CUSTOMER_ID
  WHERE t.booking_date BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) AND trunc(sysdate+21)
  AND f.type='NEW'
  );
```